# What will happen tags when the trunk get deleted in SVN

Tags: svn

Let's say I have created tags and branches from the trunk and delete the trunk. What will happen to the tags and branches once I delete the trunk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing will happen to the tags and branches if you delete the trunk. If you are deleting something from SVN, you are just removing it from the current state of the SVN. Any time you can go back to the older revision and see the trunk though you delete.

Answer (score 3):

You are not deleting the trunk in the past, you are deleting the trunk in the present.  The previously existing references to the past versions of the trunk will still be present.